# jqGrid with JSON outputting [object 0bject]

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I ran into a problem with [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) and JSON data. Basically the grid will not display any of the data, but instead outputs [object Object] into the first column of the table. Below is a **snippet** of the data I am using. It is valid JSON.

```
{
    "currpage": "1",
    "totalpages": "3",
    "totalrecords": "70",
    "rows": [
    {
        "id": "uid\u003dAndrewBryant",
        "cells": [
            {
                "HOURS_ENTITLED": "203",
                "HOURS_TAKEN": 0,
                "NAME": "uid\u003dAndrewBryant",
                "SICKNESS_TAKEN": 0,
                "TAKEN_TOIL": 0,
                "TOTAL_TOIL": 0,
                "YEAR_ENTILEMENT": "2011"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Below is the code I am using to call the jqGrid functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#statsTable").jqGrid({
        url: "http://cw-epuip-d01.tm-gnet.com:10040/wps/PA_Resource_Manager_1/JSONServlet",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "get",
        jsonReader : {
            root: "rows",
            cell:"cells",
            page: "currpage",
              total: "totalpages",
              records: "totalrecords",
               id: "id"
        },
        colNames: ['NAME', 'HOURS ENTITLED', 'HOURS TAKEN'  ],
        colModel: [
                  {name:'NAME', index:'NAME'},
                  {name:'HOURS_ENTITLED', index:'HOURS_ENTITLED'},
                  {name:'HOURS_TAKEN', index:'HOURS_TAKEN'}
            ]
    }
    );
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would not recommend you to use "uid=AndrewBryant" as `id` value. You should understand that it will follows to the `<tr id="uid=AndrewBryant">` which is really bad. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) for the description of correct ids.

Next you can read the JSON file which server currently produce with small changes in the `jsonReader` (additional `repeatitems:false`) and additional `jsonmap` property for every column

```
jsonReader : {
    root: "rows",
    page: "currpage",
    total: "totalpages",
    records: "totalrecords",
    repeatitems: false
},
colModel: [
          {name:'NAME', index:'NAME',jsonmap:'cells.0.NAME'},
          {name:'HOURS_ENTITLED', index:'HOURS_ENTITLED',
           jsonmap:'cells.0.HOURS_ENTITLED'},
          {name:'HOURS_TAKEN', index:'HOURS_TAKEN',jsonmap:'cells.0.HOURS_TAKEN'}
]
```

after the changes the grid will be displayed: see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/JonathanP.htm).

Nevertheless I would recommend you better to make some changes in server code and produce more standard JSON which can be read without `jsonmap`. See [the jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data).